# Configure how React app is started in production

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

`create-react-app` and `npm` noob here, and I'm having some trouble with deploying to production. When I start my app, I want to start a specific js file, as well as run the normal `react-scripts start`. So in my `package.json`, I have the following.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node -r esm src/server.js & react-scripts start",
  ...
}
```

When I run `npm start`, it works great, both scripts are executed locally and up and running.

My cursory reading seems to indicate that `npm start` is just for development though. In production, the `build/` folder will be used and... I can't figure out how it's run. Testing locally, after running `npm run build`, the `build/` folder is made. And then running `serve -s build`, something is executed, but it's not my `npm start` script. It looks like it's just `react-scripts start`. Attempting to deploy to several real-life production servers like Firebase and Netlify behaves the same way.

So how exactly is the production build started? And how can I configure it to behave like my development build.

I feel like I must be misunderstanding something fundamental as I can't find any explanation online, but any help would be appreciated.

If you're interested in why exactly I have this strange setup, I'm attempting to deploy [boardgame.io](https://github.com/nicolodavis/boardgame.io) with a multiplayer server.

Comment: When you run `npm run build`, all of your code gets packaged into a static site. That's what is within the build folder. So if you were to just go into build and open index.html, the site should appear as intended. "Making the server run" just means serving up the index.html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to use `npm start` is so that you can fire up a local web server on the fly and paired with `nodemon` and other goodies, changes to the source can easily be viewed as if it were in production.

`npm build` transpiles the source into a lightweight, lazy loading bundle suitable for production. Once the build is complete, you use a web server to host `build/index.html` and access the site from there. What you use to host it is up to you (most commonly `nginx` but you *could* use something like `apache` or `node` like you're alluding to with `serve -s build`).

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand how it works properly now. Is it because in my `package.json`, the `main` is `src/index.js`, that file is run, which renders its component on the `"root"` element in `index.html`? So if I wanted to also run `src/server.js`, the simple way would be to have a separate project with `main` as `src/server.js`? But my `server.js` needs code found in the same project so I was trying to avoid that

Comment: The build will take care of all the client stuff, you just need to host the directory. Since you're using a MERN stack, most people will have two separate projects, client & server. Personally I wouldn't really worry about that for smaller projects. In production, along with hosting the build directory, you also need node to be running `src/server.js` all the time (and restarting if crashed). You can use something like `pm2` to do that.